# Is it possible to use regular buttons as radio button in RadioGroup?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I am using below code . Can it be done using CSS or any other option of materials. In addition to that, Can I have different colour button for selected one.

```
 values=["male","female"]

      <RadioGroup value={value} onChange={handleChange} >
       {values.map((value) => (
        <FormControlLabel value={value} control={<Radio />} label={value} />
        ))}
      </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: please explain what libraries are u using for the component `RadioGroup`...

Comment: @adirabargil 1) Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';
2) RadioGroup from '@material-ui/core/RadioGroup';
3) FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';

Comment: @adirabargil You can refer: https://codesandbox.io/s/ggzku?file=/demo.js

Comment: it seems material-ui doesnt have one themselves...